# forward-sexp goes to eol in python mode (but only sometimes)

Tags: python, navigation

When I run the command `forward-sexp` at the beginning of the line in Python mode, my cursor jumps to the end of the line.  I assume that the line is a statement, and is therefore considered to be a sexp.  Can I modify this behavior so that forward-sexp only jumps to the end of the symbol?

### Steps to Reproduce:

Paste the following lines into a buffer in Python mode

```
def dummy():
    my_count_variable = 0
    (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3)
    return my_count_variable
```

**Case 1:**

- Move the cursor to the `m` at the beginning of `my_count_variable`
- Call `forward-sexp` (`C-M-f`)
- Notice that the cursor has jumped to the end of the line
- (I would prefer to jump to the end of the symbol here)

**Case 2:**

- Place the cursor at the beginning of the second line, just under the `d` in `def`
- Call `forward-sexp` (`C-M-f`)
- Notice that the cursor has moved to the end of `my_count_variable`
- (This seems inconsistent with Case 1)

**Case 3:**

- Place the cursor at the first `(` on the third line
- Call `forward-sexp` (`C-M-f`)
- Notice that the cursor jumps to the end of the first tuple instead of the end of the statement.
- (Again, why not jump to the end of the expression?)

**Is there a way to modify the behavior of `forward-sexp` so that it does not treat a python "statement" as a balanced expression?**  There seems to be some inconsistency which causes the command to work how I want, but only sometimes (i.e. cases 2 and 3).

**Note:** I am using the built-in python-mode from python.el

Comment: You should mention the python mode you're using.

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug?  This is the behavior that I would expect.

Comment: @Qudit: I never suggested that it was a bug.  Although I do believe there is an inconsistency.  I am looking for a way to modify the behavior.  I will modify the post to make this clearer.

Comment: @nispio It's true that it's arguably inconsistent.  The problem is that forward-sexp is an inherently ambiguous concept in non-lisp languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd agree it's an inconsistency (w.r.t. other programming modes); I ended up here searching for the same answer.

Ultimately, I found the answer in the **python.el** source code (version 0.24.2) which contains:

> If you prefer *cc-mode*-like *forward-sexp* movement, setting
>   *forward-sexp-function* to nil is enough, You can do that using
>   the *python-mode-hook*:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
        (lambda () (setq forward-sexp-function nil)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is correct and the expected one.

```
forward-sexp
```

means:
Move forward across one balanced expression. However, what should be "balanced"?
Obviously this is a very general term. Emacs takes a single word as balanced expression, but not a single operator-sign. Lists are commonly well detected as balanced.

When starting from "(" in your example, call `python-nav-end-of-statement`.